# How to set Angular to use a subdomain?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app that works great if hosted on the root. But when I host it on a subdomain, it can't load any resources.

For example, my app is hosted at:

domain.com/app

When loading the page, the console throws errors like:

```
GET domain.com/polyfills.12345.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

How would I set the Angular configuration to tell it that it is hosted under a subdomain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<base href="appFolder">` to index.html. It is used to resolve assets relative paths.

Note that index.html can be returned not only for `http://smth.com/appFolder` but also for `http://smth.com/appFolder/route1/subroute2`, base href is used here to understand what is appFolder and what is internal route

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there any way to make it dynamic? For example on the localhost there would be no subdomain, but when hosting there would be.